# Confused as to why the cleanup function runs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The cleanup function is being ran on application launch, which isn't what I'd expect, given `useEffect`'s dependencies. `query` doesn't change.

What am I missing?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const [query, setQuery] = useState("interstellar");

useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

    async function fetchMovies() {
      try {
        setError("");
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch(
          `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${KEY}&s=${query}`,
          { signal: controller.signal }
        );
        if (!res.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch movies");
        const data = await res.json();
        if (data.Response === "False") throw new Error("No movies found");
        setMovies(data.Search);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        if (err.name !== "AbortError") setError(err.message);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }

    if (!query) {
      setMovies([]);
      setError("");
      return;
    }

    fetchMovies();

    return () => controller.abort();
  }, [query]);
```

In my code, based on my understanding of `useEffect`, it would run on mount, and when the `query` dependency changes. As `query` doesn't change, that would mean that `useEffect` should only run on mount, and its' cleanup function would never run, as `useEffect` shouldn't get called again.

Comment: What version of react are you using and is strict mode enabled?

Comment: Ah, it was strict mode that was causing useEffect to be re-run. Thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect was being re-run due to Strict Mode, which consequently would trigger the cleanup function.